# ASP.NET C# Error: The Type must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters, reference, directcast

I have a class: Constants.cs

Code:

```
namespace DataAccess.Utilities
{
  public class Constants
  {
    public enum ReturnCode
    {
      Fail = -1,
      Success = 0,
      Warning = 1
    }
  }
}
```

This is my code for directcast class

```
public static T DirectCast<T>(object o) where T : class
{
    T value = o as T;
    if (value == null && o != null)
    {
        throw new InvalidCastException();
    }
    return value;
}
```

Here is my code that get's error

```
code = DirectCast<Constants.ReturnCode>(int.Parse(db.GetParameterValue(command, "RESULTCODE").ToString().Trim()));
```

Error Message:

> Error 2   The type 'DataAccess.Utilities.Constants.ReturnCode' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'DataAccess.DataManager.QueueingManager.DirectCast(object)'

Before I am using DirectCast from .net vb, but DirectCast is not exist in c# so I try searching and I get some codes on how to create DirectCast that has same function to vb.

Comment: I don't understand you're asking. The error message is crystal clear, and is caused because you are trying to use a value type where a reference type is required. What is your _question_? Why do you have the `where T : class` constraint, if you want to use the method with things other than classes?

Comment: `where T : class` but `ReturnCode` is **enum not class**

Comment: I just want to convert this code from vb to c#........ Dim code As Constants.ReturnCode = DirectCast(Integer.Parse(db.GetParameterValue(Command, "RESULTCODE").ToString.Trim), Constants.ReturnCode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
code = DirectCast<Constants.ReturnCode>(int.Parse(db.GetParameterValue(command, "RESULTCODE").ToString().Trim()));
```

Should be changed to:

```
code = DirectCast<Constants>(int.Parse(db.GetParameterValue(command, "RESULTCODE").ToString().Trim()));
```

Or, do it like this: see working example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fail = Constants.DirectCast<Constants.ReturnCode>(-1);
        var success = Constants.DirectCast<Constants.ReturnCode>(0);
        var warning = Constants.DirectCast<Constants.ReturnCode>(1);
        Console.WriteLine(fail);
        Console.WriteLine(success);
        Console.WriteLine(warning);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Constants
{
    public enum ReturnCode
    {
        Fail = -1,
        Success = 0,
        Warning = 1
    }

    public static T DirectCast<T>(object o)
    {
        T value = (T)o;
        if (value == null && o != null)
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException();
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'DataAccess.Utilities.Constants' to 'DataAccess.Utilities.Constants.ReturnCode'

Comment: Thanks... I used code = Constants.DirectCast<Constants.ReturnCode>(int.Parse(db.GetParameterValue(command, "RESULTCODE").ToString().Trim()));

Answer (score 1):

In .NET, there are value types and reference types. Classes are reference types for example, they are like pointers in C++.
int are value types, enums also.
In generics, only reference types can be use as type arguments .

You can remove the genericity of your method but you won't be able to know the return type. Moreover, "as" won't work with enum because it's a value type.

I don't understand why you want to cast an enum, you can parse it :

```
Enum.Parse(typeof(Constants.ReturnCode), db.GetParameterValue(command, "RESULTCODE").ToString().Trim()));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. finally my code works.

```
 public class Constants
 {
    public enum ReturnCode
    {
        Fail = -1,
        Success = 0,
        Warning = 1
    }
 }


 public static T DirectCast<T>(object o)
    {
        T value= (T)o;
        if (value== null && o != null)
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException();
        }
        return value;
    }


 code = Constants.DirectCast<Constants.ReturnCode>(int.Parse(db.GetParameterValue(command, "RESULTCODE").ToString().Trim()));
```